# Zoom while cropping in Lightroom Classic

Tags: lightroom, cropping

I've got a bunch of paintings that I need to crop in Lightroom, but I want them to be pixel perfect crops.  As far as I can tell, there is no way to zoom in while cropping.  Without being able to zoom in, it's almost impossible to crop to the correct pixel.  I saw someone mention using a second monitor to get a better idea of what they were cropping, but I'm not sure what they're referring to.

Does anyone have a good workflow that they recommend for this sort of problem?  The goal is to have all of the paintings level and cropped to their exact edges.  Do I just need to use Photoshop?  If so, what's the best workflow to export, crop, then re-import to Lightroom?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a two monitor setup, you can open up a secondary display (F11). You can zoom the secondary monitor to 1:1 (Ctrl+Shift+=, or, Window -> Secondary Display -> Zoom In). This technique is will be frustrating as it takes the secondary monitor display a few seconds to update.

If you need to zoom in while cropping and leveling, export the image to Photoshop (Ctrl+E, or, Photo -> Edit In -> Edit in Adobe Photoshop) or another image editing program like GIMP (Ctrl+Alt+E) where you can zoom in to set your crop edge precisely. If using Photoshop, then going back & forth from LR to PS is painless, although, you'll end up with another copy of your edited image.

Be sure to take advantage of LR's *Lens Corrections* and *Transform* before cropping. The transform function can correct for keystoning and auto level your image if you have straight edges (frame edges).